# Legality on sharing rom dumps on abandoned hardware

Tags: disassembly, rom

I have an old piece of HP test gear from the 80's that HP no longer supports. I want to add in a feature and need to dump roms and figure things out to do that.

How can I share my process and findings on a personal blog without legal issues?

If a company no longer supports a product can I dump a rom and share it with the community? I physically own the hardware so I can be in possession of the rom I would imagine. If I don't share the entire rom can I copy sections of it to post to help clarify a post?

This also applies to the old schematics in the manuals. Can I post screenshots or not??